# Django template date comparison

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm trying to compare dates in my html template. If the current date falls between the start and end date, it will display available. However, my current code only shows `Not available` even when my date falls between the start and end date.

The now variable is generated by dateTime.now() and is passed to the html. The dates are in the format `April 16, 2018, 1:44 p.m.` using Django's `DateTimeField`

```
<tbody>
    {% for key in keys%}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{key.name}}</th>
        <td>{{key.lock}}</td>
        <td>{{key.start_date}}</td>
        <td>{{key.end_date}}</td>
        {% if now >= key.start_date and now <= key.end_date %}
        <td>Available</td>
        {% else %}
        <td>Not Available</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">Unlock</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Code from views.py

```
    keys = Key.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    dateTimeNow = datetime.now()
    args = {'keys': keys, 'now': dateTimeNow}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: use custom template tag

Comment: You can add an `is_available` method to your key model where you do the logic check. That will be easier to debug and more optimized too

Comment: @RamkishoreM So i have to update that field everytime i do a database fetch for all the data?

Comment: Don't need a field. just a method `def is_available(self):`. This makes it reusable too. It is a good idea to keep such logic inside model

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method to your Key model:

```
@property
def is_now(self):
    """
    Returns whether the key is active now
    :return:
    """
    return self.start_date < timezone.now() < self.end_date
```

Now in your template:

```
 {% for key in keys%}
    {% if key.is_now %} 
        available
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I get it if it is used to retrieve one item from the database. Can i know how can i append the available data to my result after i extract multiple rows? Im using a for loop in the html template to retrieve data from each row

Comment: @Eneres Can you provide code to explain what you mean?